# Contextual filter in views

Tags: views

I have a form on my site. Each time a user submits the form they are directed to a confirmation page like this;

> eform/help-request/confirm?entityform_id=1

I want to create a view that has a contextual filter that picks the last form submitted by the user and displays the fields from that form only.

I have a view that shows the field content from the form as it was submitted by the user but i cannot get the view to only display the *latest* form submission from the user...
As i have it my view is displaying *all* the forms the user has ever submitted ... which i don't want.

Any help appreciated. I know I am close (ish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the view by created desc.

Then limit the view to only show 1 row.

The remaining item will be the last form submitted.

Comment: I tried this initially and had some trouble - I believe because of my pager settings.

Use pager: Display a specified number of items | 1 item


Worked...Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.